# Checking Maybe values

Tags: haskell, option-type

I am just a beginner in Haskell, and I try to do [cryptopals](http://cryptopals.com) crypto challenges in Haskell.

I wrote the following code:

```
import Data.Char

nibbleToInt :: Char -> Int
nibbleToInt c
    | ('0' <= c && c <= '9') = (ord c) - 48
    | ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') = (ord c) - 87
    | ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') = (ord c) - 55
    | otherwise = error "Boom"


hexToInt :: String -> Int
hexToInt (x:y:[]) = nibbleToInt x * 16 + nibbleToInt y
hexToInt _ = error "Boom"

hexToInts :: String -> [Int]
hexToInts [] = []
hexToInts (n1:n2:ns) = [hexToInt $ [n1] ++ [n2]] ++ (hexToInts ns)
hexToInts _ = error "Boom"

main = do
    print $ hexToInts "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d"
```

This code seems to work, but I am sure that it can be improved!

I refactored the `nibbleToInt` function to use a `Maybe`:

```
nibbleToInt :: Char -> Maybe Int
nibbleToInt c
    | ('0' <= c && c <= '9') = Just ((ord c) - 48)
    | ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') = Just ((ord c) - 87)
    | ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') = Just ((ord c) - 55)
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

However, then, I do not know how to rewrite the function hexToInt, as it calls the `nibbleToInt` function twice, which returns the `Maybe Int`. I do not know how to test those two values.

Any help is welcome, as I do not know any Haskell programmer around me...

Comment: Applicative composition is what you need. Lookup `liftA2` or `<*>` and `<$>` in Hoogle.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer !

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Maybe` monad to chain together a sequence of operations that should only happen if the value is a `Just`.  If the value is a `Nothing`, then the chain will stop:

```
hexToInt :: String -> Maybe Int
hexToInt (x:y:[]) = do
    a <- nibbleToInt x  -- chain will end if nibbleToInt evaluates to Nothing
    b <- nibbleToInt y  -- chain will end if nibbleToInt evaluates to Nothing
    return (a * 16 + b) -- chain completed successfully
hexToInt _ = Nothing

hexToInts :: String -> Maybe [Int]
hexToInts [] = return []
hexToInts (n1:n2:ns) = do
    i <- hexToInt (n1:[n2]) -- chain will end if hexToInt evaluates to Nothing
    is <- hexToInts ns      -- chain will end if hexToInts evaluates to Nothing
    return (i:is)           -- chain completed successfully
hexToInts _ = Nothing
```

You could also use `Applicative` style which does the same thing in a more functional style:

```
hexToInt :: String -> Maybe Int
hexToInt (x:y:[]) = f <$> nibbleToInt x <*> nibbleToInt y where
    f a b = a * 16 + b
hexToInt _ = Nothing

hexToInts :: String -> Maybe [Int]
hexToInts [] = return []
hexToInts (n1:n2:ns) = (:) <$> hexToInt (n1:[n2]) <*> hexToInts ns
hexToInts _ = Nothing
```

Note that `hexToInts` can use `splitAt` to break the list:

```
hexToInts :: String -> Maybe [Int]
hexToInts [] = return []
hexToInts ns = (:) <$> hexToInt a <*> hexToInts as where
    (a, as) = splitAt 2 ns
```

Or write a helper function to pair-up the elements of the list, and use `mapM` to apply the monadic function over the pairs:

```
toPairs :: [a] -> [[a]]
toPairs [] = []
toPairs xs = a : toPairs as where
    (a, as) = splitAt 2 xs

hexToInts :: String -> Maybe [Int]
hexToInts = mapM hexToInt . toPairs
```